# Nested Grid IN EXTJS

Tags: extjs

HI

How to design Nested grids in ExtJS
Please provide some samples(How to use RowExpander in ExtJS GridPanel)

Comment: This is a concrete example: http://www.programering.com/a/MDN4cTMwATY.html

Comment: Thank you, MacGyver. this is what I want.

Answer (score 7):

Try something like this:

```
 //Create the Row Expander.
var expander = new Ext.ux.grid.RowExpander({
     tpl : new Ext.Template('<div id="myrow-{Id}" ></div>')
});

//Define the function to be called when the row is expanded.
function expandedRow(obj, record, body, rowIndex){
    //absId parameter for the http request to get the absence details.
    var absId = record.get('Id');

    var dynamicStore = //the new store for the nested grid.

    //Use Id to give each grid a unique identifier. The Id is used in the row expander tpl.
    //and in the grid.render("ID") method.
    var row = "myrow-" + record.get("Id");
    var id2 = "mygrid-" + record.get("Id");  

   //Create the nested grid.         
   var gridX = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        store: dynamicStore,
        stripeRows: true,
        columns: [
            //columns
        ],
        height: 120,
        id: id2                  
    });        

    //Render the grid to the row expander template(tpl).
    gridX.render(row);
    gridX.getEl().swallowEvent([ 'mouseover', 'mousedown', 'click', 'dblclick' ]);
}

//Add an expand listener to the Row Expander.
expander.on('expand', expandedRow);
```

You can find more information on this [Here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?24287-Nested-Grids-Problem&highlight=gridpanel+expandedrow)

Answer (score 2):

How to use RowExpander in grid? Here's an example: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/grid-plugins.html

More examples can be found from http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do it as the others have mentioned, however I recommend against it.

Reasons:
Memory leaks due to the sub-grids not being destroyed properly.
Selection model doesn't work correctly
Events get messed up.

Comment: Could you provide more insight to those memory leaks?

Comment: memory leak occurs, because the grid gets destroyed in the DOM when the grid refreshes, but the attached event handlers etc still exist in JS.